# How to compare pointer to struct to NULL?

Tags: python, null, cython

I have this in Cython:

```
cdef extern from "lib/bindings.h":
    ctypedef struct parser:
        yyscan_t yyscanner
        ...
```

And related C code:

```
typedef struct {
    yyscan_t yyscanner;
    ...
} _parser, *parser;
```

Now, when I try:

```
cdef parser p = ...
if p != NULL:
    ...
```

And get:

```
Invalid types for '!=' (parser, void *)
```

Why? Does Cython misinterpret `parser` declaration? It seems like it doesn't "understand" that `parser` is a pointer type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cython doesn't read your C code at all - it just `#include`s the relevant files blindly and uses your Cython `ctypedef` to understand what's going on. Since you haven't shown pointers in your Cython code it has no way of knowing that `parser` is a pointer type.

The correct declaration would be something like

```
cdef extern from "lib/bindings.h":
    ctypedef struct _parser:
        yyscan_t yyscanner
        # ...
    ctypedef _parser* parser
```